# Highlight result of dataframe comparison where values differ

Tags: python, pandas

I need to compare 2 DataFrames (which should be identical) and output an Excel sheet that shows the comparison between them, with any mismatched values highlighted. This was the format requested by the analysts working with the reports.

I'm currently using df.compare() to do this, which gives a result like the below, where orig is the original df and new is the new df.

In the below, both values in col_1 at index 3 should be highlighted, because they didn't match between the dataframes:

```
index col_1      col_2      col_3
      orig  new  orig  new  orig  new
1     1     1    2     2    3     3
2     1     1    2     2    3     3
3     1     2    2     2    3     3
```

While I can do this on my own, the dataframes could be very large, and there will be hundreds of comparisons. So I need your help in doing it efficiently!

My idea was to do

```
orig.compare(new, keep_equal=False)
```

and use that to create a mask. This would work because keep_equal=False only returns values that differ, all other cells are NaN. Then I could run the comparison again with keep_equal=True, which populates all cells. Then finally apply the mask using

```
df.style.apply
```

to highlight the values that didn't match.

Is there a faster way to do this? It requires processing all the cells in the df several times.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

`orig` and `new` are the two dataframes you want to compare.

Use:

```py
def highlight_diffs(orig, props=''):
    return np.where(orig != new, props, '')

orig.style.apply(highlight_diffs, props='color:white;background-color:darkblue', axis=None)
```

Reference: [Styler Functions. Acting on Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html#Acting-on-Data).